# How to get a list of all Entity relation in Entity Framework 6.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity, relation

I am trying to get a list of all relations "foreign keys" on a model programmatically (key, related object, foreign column name.)

I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817289/entity-framework-finding-foreign-keys) which seems to be doing the same thing. But I am unable to get the code in the answer to work for me.

Here is what I have done

```
    public List<string> GetObjectRelations(Type type)
    {

        var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

        // Get the part of the model that contains info about the actual CLR types
        var objectItemCollection = ((ObjectItemCollection)metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));

        var fk = metadata.GetItems<AssociationType>(DataSpace.CSpace).Where(a => a.IsForeignKey);

        //check if the table has any foreign constraints for that column
        var fkname = fk.Where(x => x.ReferentialConstraints[0].ToRole.Name == type.Name).Where(x => x.ReferentialConstraints[0].ToProperties[0].Name == type.Name);

        //Get the corresponding reference entity column name
        return fkname.Select(x => x.ReferentialConstraints[0].FromProperties[0].Name).ToList();

    }
```

Here is how I call this method

```
var relations = QueryExtractor.GetObjectRelations(typeof(TSource));
```

But this code is not working for me. The return value is empty.

How can I correctly get the foreign key and the object that they are are related to?

**UPDATED**

Here is my current code based on muratgu answer below. But it is still now giving me a list of the relations

```
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetObjectRelations(Type type)
    {
        var relations = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

        var fk_all = metadata.GetItems<AssociationType>(DataSpace.CSpace).Where(a => a.IsForeignKey);

        var fk_out = fk_all.Where(x => x.ReferentialConstraints[0].ToRole.Name == type.Name).ToList(); // relations going out 

        foreach (var fk in fk_out)
        {
            var relation = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            var fk_ref = fk.ReferentialConstraints[0]; //How can a foreign key relation have more than one column?

            var objectName = fk_ref.FromRole.Name;

            var attributeName = fk_ref.FromProperties[0].Name;

            relation.Add(objectName, attributeName);

            relations.Add(relation);
        }

        return relations;
    }
```

Comment: Let's say `Entity2` has a foreign key called `Fk1` that points to `Entity1`.`Id`, what do you want to see on that list?

Comment: I want to see the foreign key "i.e ClientId" and I also want to know the object that it points to "i.e "Client" and I want to know the remote key "i.e Id"

Answer (score 1):

You already had everything you need in your snippet of code, although I have a hunch that returning a list of strings is not going to be enough for you. I will break it down, so you can decide what to do with the results.

```
        // assume Child has a foreign key (Parent_Id) to Parent (Id)
        // assume primary keys are not composite
        var type = typeof(Child); 
        var fk_all = metadata.GetItems<AssociationType>(DataSpace.CSpace).Where(a => a.IsForeignKey);
        var fk_out = fk_all.Where(x => x.ReferentialConstraints[0].ToRole.Name == type.Name).ToList(); // relations going out 
        foreach(var fk in fk_out) { // could be many
            var fk_ref = fk.ReferentialConstraints[0]; // what if more than one?
            Console.WriteLine("From {0} - {1} ", fk_ref.FromRole.Name, fk_ref.FromProperties[0].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("To {0} - {1} ", fk_ref.ToRole.Name, fk_ref.ToProperties[0].Name);
        }
```

Assuming `Child` has a foreign key `Parent_Id` to `Parent` (`Id`), this will print:

```
        From Parent - Id
        To Child - Parent_Id
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I apologize it took me a while to be able to test it. The fk_all returns one object but the fk_out line returns 0 records. I will update my question now with my recent code

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37813248/6372257), you can use the [Entity Framework Mapping Api Extensions](https://efmappingapi.codeplex.com/documentation). For example, the following line retrieves the foreign keys for the Product type:

```
string[] fks = context.Db<Product>().Fks.Select(fk => fk.PropertyName).ToArray();
```