# Get foreign key reference type from Entity Framework metadata without reference property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two entity types:

```
public record Person : BaseEntity
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Guid CarFk { get; set; }
}

public record Car : BaseEntity
{
}

public record BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasOne<Car>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CarFk);
```

I need to know on which property foreign key references. But `EntityEntry.Metadata.GetReferencingForeignKeys()` returns no keys.

How can I get type of reference entity?

Comment: Maybe help https://stackoverflow.com/a/10911146/4588756

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but the `PrimaryKey` will default to Id.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt

Comment: ..... or to `(entity)Id` - e.g. `PersonId` - both options are available and possible

Comment: It's not what I need. I have a model configuration which binded without reference entity. And I need to get Car type from Controller. I don't know what type of entity I got. And I need to log type of entity binded to foreign key if entity has if it exists.

Comment: @Gbsyi Can you please add your controller code to the ticket to help us understand?